# How to stop academic journal page from redirecting

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

How can I get a link from ScienceDirect to not redirect?

```
url <- "https://doi.org/10.1016/j.isci.2020.101838"
rvest::read_html(url) %>% 
      html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="abspara0010"]') %>%
      html_text()
# Fails
```

I have a large database of papers:

```
pangiaoDB <- read_html('https://panglaodb.se/papers.html')
table <- pangiaoDB %>% 
 html_node(xpath = '/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/table') %>% 
 html_table()
url <- lapply(table$DOI, function(x) {
    paste('https://doi.org/', x, sep = '')
})
head(url)
```

I am able to parse and extract abstracts from more than half the articles by using a combination of `rvest::read_html` and `rcrossref::cr_abstract` however, some articles are redirected causing both methods to fail.

The redirected link for `https://doi.org/10.1016/j.isci.2020.101838` works fine:

```
url <-"https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S258900422031035X?via%3Dihub"
rvest::read_html(url) %>% 
      html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="abspara0010"]') %>%
      html_text()
# Works
```

I have tried to catch the redirected link using a custom function

```
trace_redirects <- function(url) {
  httr::GET(url)$all_headers %>%
    lapply(function(x) x$headers$location) %>%
    unlist() %>%
    unique()
}
redirected <- trace_redirects("https://doi.org/10.1016/j.isci.2020.101838")
```

Which returns `https://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S258900422031035X`, however working with this link also fails

```
url <- redirected 
rvest::read_html(url) %>% 
      html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="abspara0010"]') %>%
      html_text()
# Fails
```

Comment: While you can reject content from a redirected URL you can't prevent the server from redirecting.

Comment: So it is not possible to get use the DOI link to get the abstract using rvest?

Comment: I looked at your prior question and raised a question about whether you would intend to visit all DOIs rather than journals. I noticed the above and I also noticed that some of the re-directs have no abstract. You need to decide what to do in these cases. It is not simply a case of a generic pattern you can apply to all links.

Comment: A bit off-topic, but I just tried throwing the DOI you gave me into a professional citation manager like citavi and it magically retrieved the abstract. You could use R to automatically write a bibtex file with all entries just as DOIs and some id, e.g. ```@article{id1,
  doi = {10.1016/j.isci.2020.101838}
}
``` through `writeLines`, import to Citavi (or zotero or whatever) and ask Citavi to enrich the publications and export as bibtex again. I know, it aint rvest nor beautiful, but oyu might get a lot more info.

Comment: @QHarr, you raise a good question and make an excellent point; I plan to visit all the DOIs, and I am aware that not all the re-directs have abstracts. My current method returns the abstracts from almost half the database. Suppose I can catch the re-directs that point to abstracts; that would be an improvement. I am not looking for 100%, just most of them. If there isn't a way to extract the abstract from the above using its DOI, I will close the question, but I posted it to see if it was possible.

Comment: Have you established how re-directions occurs?

Comment: It appears Elsevier https://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/help has a service to redirect links. So the DOI link redirects to their "linking hub" and then is redirected to the actual journal. I imagine this is not the only DOI that behaves this way, so if there is a pattern I can add to my script, I will be able to catch more articles. Maybe the issue is that the link is redirected twice? I am not sure if this makes a difference.

Comment: If this is an exercise in practising scraping, please disregard this and my above comment, but I followed my suggestion above and Citavi retrieved all but 90 of the 4568 abstracts. This makes sense, as they probably employ entire teams to write proper scrapers for their firefox entensions. If you really want to get the abstracts this would definitely be easier, as they cover most journals that are out there. Through the bibtex package I was then able to read these back into R.

Comment: Thank you for the input. Yes, this is an attempt to practice web scraping and filtering based on keywords in abstracts. I want to keep everything in R or Python, and it seems there is no way in Zotero or Citava to retrieve this information in those programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that some of the journals have patterns in their redirects. The issue I brought up in this post appears to be unique to the journal `iScience`.

```
issue_j <- table %>% subset(Journal == 'iScience') %>%
select(Title, DOI) %>%
mutate(DOI = paste0('https://doi.org/',DOI))
head(issue_j)
```

The database has a total of 25 publications from this journal 
`length(issue_j$DOI)`

So I wrote a function to catch the first redirect that points to a unique identifier for each publication. The function then extracts this and pastes it to the link where the DOI is redirected to.

```
isci <- function (url) 
    {
    if (str_detect(url, pattern = 'isci')) {
    
    redirect <- httr::GET(url)[["url"]]
    new_url <- paste0('https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/',
                      gsub(".*/","",redirect), '?via%3Dihub')
    
    abstract <- rvest::read_html(new_url) %>% 
      html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="abssec0010"]') %>%
      html_text()
        
    return(abstract)
        
} else cat('done!')
}
```

When I plug the DOI into the function, the abstract is returned.

```
isci('https://doi.org/10.1016/j.isci.2020.101655')
```

I can not speak for all publications in this journal but this works for all the publications from this journal in the database I am working with.

```
# Returns all 25 abstracts
doi.list <- as.list(issue_j$DOI)
lapply(doi.list, isci)
```

In conclusion, it seems if I want to do this through web scraping I will have to find patterns specific to journals and add them to a script. Lastly, @QHarr makes a good point in saying that not all redirects point to abstracts.